# Retrieving friends' birthdays using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to get the list of birthdays of friends using facebook graph api in the following manner

```
$user_friends = $facebook->api( '/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday' ) ;
 foreach ($user_friends as $friend)
 {
    echo $friend['birthday'];  
 }
```

I have the neccessary permission for viewing birthdays. When I do `print_r($friend)`, I get all the details i.e. id, name and birthday but not getting birthdays in the above manner, Why?

Although, I have already implemented it using FQL, I was trying to do it in this manner. Can you please point out my mistake. I'm using it in an *in-facebook app*. Thanks

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($friend)` and post result in your answer?

Comment: Following is part of the output of `var_dump($friend)` in  the app `array(238) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(8) "14740752"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "SSSSS AAAAA"
    ["birthday"]=>
    string(10) "06/01/1981"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(8) "62345408"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "JJJ BBBB"["birthday"]=>
    string(10) "26/11/1983"
  } }`

Comment: I think you should add another foreach loop

Comment: your method also worked, Thanks

Comment: i'm glad it helped. I can post answer if you want to accept it

Comment: @Fabio Sure, i'll do !!

Comment: I just posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api response is actually an array, with the friends data in the `['data']` key, so the loop should be

```
foreach ($user_friends['data'] as $friend)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look to your `var_dump()` and I think you should add another foreach loop since `$friend` is an array as well

```
$user_friends = $facebook->api( '/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday' ) ;
foreach ($user_friends as $friend)
{
    foreach($friend as $fr)
    {
        echo $fr['birthday'];  
    }
}
```